# window.open - js in source doesn't load

Tags: javascript

I'm opening a new window with js like this

```
var json = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
var wnd = window.open("about:blank", "My Title", "...");
wnd.document.write(json["html"]);
```

The string in `json["html"]`contains `<script>` Tags in itself, but those won't load. Only when I reload the already opened pop-up, the scripts apply.

How can I make the scripts in the pop-up window's source load immediately?

Comment: `var wnd = window.open("about:blank", "My Title", "...");
wnd.document.write("<script>alert('works');</script>");` This works. So i'm guessing the problem is at the `script` tag you are trying to run. What is it?

Comment: It's a jQuery-Script, handling elements of the HTML. It's hooked in by `jQuery(document).ready(main);`. The `json["html"]` isn't only script-code, it's full html with script tags in the head.

Comment: So try to eliminate unnecessary code from it until you find the problematic piece of code and share it.

Comment: @Maor The problem isn't the jQuery in the pop-up. The problem is: The jQuery in the pop-up doesn't load. It only loads when I refresh the pop-up.

Comment: This is not a "popup" per se, this is a brand new page. Did you load jQuery before using it in your script? because if not it will not be defined